# Number theorems as pagenumber.counter

Tags: numbering, theorems

For my thesis I want to number theorem-like environments as `(pagenumber).(counter)`, where `counter` is a counter shared among all environments which restarts at every page. So for example, on page 86 I would have

> **Definition 86.1.** Aaa
>
> **Theorem 86.2.** Bbb
>
> **Remark 86.3.** Ccc

and then, on page 87,

> **Corollary 87.1.** Ddd
>
> **Proposition 87.2.** Eee

I tried to implement this with `amsthm` and `thmtools` by setting `\declaretheorem[numberwithin=page]{theorem}`, and defining all other theorem environments as siblings of theorem. When doing so, I noticed that sometimes the counters are wrong, especially when theorems appear close to the top of a page. Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[height=5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\declaretheorem[numberwithin=page]{theorem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{theorem}
        Aaa
    \end{theorem}
    
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \begin{theorem}
        Bbb
    \end{theorem}
    
    \begin{theorem}
        Ccc
    \end{theorem}
    
    \lipsum[1]
    
    aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa
    aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa
    aa aa aa aa aa aa
    
    \begin{theorem}
        Ddd
    \end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Here, the theorems on page 1 are numbered correctly, but those on pages 2 and 3 are not (1.3 and 3.0 should be 2.1 and 3.1, respectively). The problem disappears when theorems appear further down the page.

This question was already asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137200/numbering-theorems-with-page-numbers),
but the solution there seems to be incompatible with `amsthm`.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Actual output of pages, and thus numbering, is asynchronous, so it will be necessary to take that into consideration, and also to run the job multiple times to get everything into synch.  (Other participants in this forum are better equipped than I to provide workable code.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is a sound style, but the thesis is yours.

My solution involves `perpage` and `needspace`.

1. The representation `\thetheorem` is `\pageref{theorem@\theglobaltheorem}.\arabic{theorem}`. Using `\pageref` is needed because the page number cannot be known at any time during compilation and only the reference gathered in the previous run is safe (you'll be warned if the references have changed).
2. The counter `globaltheorem` is incremented after a suitable `\label` is emitted; I use `postheadhook`, but `preheadhook` might be used as well.
3. The `theorem` counter is declared to be “per page”.
4. There is a slight complication, because the counter is incremented *before* the theorem is actually typeset, so I use `preheadhook` to ensure that at least one line is available, in order to overcome this problem. You can check that if `\needspace{\baselineskip}` is omitted, the remark on page 2 would be numbered 2.3 instead of the expected 2.1.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{perpage}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{needspace}

\declaretheorem[
  name=Theorem,
  preheadhook=\needspace{\baselineskip},
  postheadhook=\label{theorem@\theglobaltheorem}\stepcounter{globaltheorem},
]{theorem}

\MakePerPage{theorem}
\newcounter{globaltheorem}
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\pageref{theorem@\theglobaltheorem}.\arabic{theorem}}

\declaretheorem[
  style=definition,
  sibling=theorem,
  name=Definition,
  preheadhook=\needspace{\baselineskip},
  postheadhook=\label{theorem@\theglobaltheorem}\stepcounter{globaltheorem},
]{definition}
\declaretheorem[
  style=definition,
  sibling=theorem,
  name=Remark,
  preheadhook=\needspace{\baselineskip},
  postheadhook=\label{theorem@\theglobaltheorem}\stepcounter{globaltheorem},
]{remark}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Aaa
\end{theorem}

\begin{definition}
Bbb
\end{definition}

\vspace{20\baselineskip}

\begin{remark}
Ccc
\end{remark}

\begin{theorem}
Ddd
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great solution, thank you very much for this! As a minor suggestion, when using `hyperref`, replace `\pageref` with `\pageref*` (`globaltheorem` is only used to give every theorem a unique label, not to be clickable). That way counters in the theorem headings are not hyperlinked and boxes around references are not "split." Also: Any particular reason why you check for `2\baselineskip` before a remark, as opposed to (1)`\baselineskip` for the other environments? Thanks again!

Comment: @user271265 The 2 has remained from a previous attempt. Yes, with `hyperref` you need `\pageref*`.